# Postmodernism and science/technology

Tags: postmodernism

Postmodernism is anti-reason and anti-modernity.

Is postmodernism also against the **philosophy of naturalism**, against the **natural sciences** and against **technology**?

Here I define postmodernism as an intellectual movement which questions the legacy of European Enlightenment philosophy and starts from Nietzsche, and goes to Heidegger, to the "French Theory" (Foucault, Derrida, Deleuze, Lacan).

Comment: "That [postmodernism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/postmodernism/) is indefinable is a truism." Having said that, we can say that the movement aims "to destabilize other concepts such as presence, identity, *historical progress, epistemic certainty*, and the *univocity of meaning*." See [Lyotard](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lyotard/): all are "language games", included sciences. This does not mean that they reject "usefulness" of science and technology.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So they play with ambiguity with regard to science and reason, as in Nietzsche's philosophy. They decribilized science and reason, but in a way that you can not really say they opposed to them. They "put into question"....

Comment: Same for truth. They did only "put into question" our access to truth. But if you say they were radical relativists, you just did not understand they profound writings.

Comment: I don't know much about it, because the writing I have seen is even greater gibberish than existentialism, but a charitable description might be: anti-story.

Comment: @ScottRowe Anti-story is how they see themselves. Their point is to decribilize everything by reducing them to simple "stories"

Comment: Beyond post-modernism.

Comment: @Starckman Lacan should be part of this discussion.

Comment: @Frank Indeed I discovered today he was considered a postmodernist :')

Comment: @Starckman I was reading yesterday that a lot of folks you cite attended his _Séminaire_ (which you can find online and is interesting to read, if you have the time)

Comment: @Starckman i think you need to distinct Postmodern culture, and Postmodern philosophy. Because Postmodern philosophy is a trying to ... dead end of Postmodern culture, since it happened because of "philosophy", "science", "moral and  ethic" and else are not same as modern(classic) time - future is here, but the (hu)man baby was fell out of the rocket "Earth" and left somewhere in extension cosmos. where is he? Is it he, or she, or it or what, why am what? You are confusing a problem and an attempt at a solution. Postmodern philosophers are not ever creators of postmodern being.

Comment: You want to get easy solution for this, but your being, your intentions, your causes - are the product of the postmodern culture. How you can solve your what?

Comment: @άνθρωπος Your idea is to say that postmodern philosophers try to help postmodern human beings to live in the postmodern world/culture?

Comment: @Frank Did you know the work of Jacques Van Rillaer? I was anaware Foucault & Cie attended Lacan's séminaires. Interesting. Do you think he had a great influence on their writings?

Comment: 'they trying to help' - philosophers not bakers or doctors. PmPhilosophers trying to woke thy up, from the postmodern hypnosis stances. But they wake up not with wakefulness of mind, but with dreams about existing. Zombi not asleep or awake, he is under hypnosis fantasies, to wake up Z needed to asleep, sleep = dead of zombie mind, this pure stance without zombie inside/but outside zombies others - without "I" inside - calls existentia. Existentia is a true reality of the dream about being. PmPhs trying to dispel the hypnosis of the butterflie's dream. not by self, but yourself is possible.

Comment: @Starckman, i thought right now about... Lady Bug))) you know, she is struggling with Akuma that looks like butterflies, but Akuma it is Japanese mythos 'demon' so you got culture blending as postmodern is. And people become mad and frustrated under akuma control, but Lady Bug(bug means logic bug/huck) she beat the akuma and make people awake in 'real'(cartoon) world. Childs like to cosplay the LB hero, and they make this neo myth existing in their childborhood reality. Thay play LB role. And also i thought about the wise and his dream about the butterfly, whose this dream his or butterfly's.

Comment: This both are dreams, but it needs to distinct whose dream. PmPhs are trying to answer.

Comment: @Starckman Will look him up, didn't know him. I thought it was more or less accepted that Lacan did have a good deal of influence over Foucault & Cie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as philosophy of naturalism - yes, all the thinkers you mentioned did not think naturalist / empirical / positivist philosophy () should be taken seriously.

As far as science and technology, the dominant trend is anti-scientific, with some interesting exceptions. I would say postmodernism is 70% anti-scientific, and 30% pro-scientific.

Nietzsche was pretty ignorant of modern science and technology, Schelling and Hegel lived 50 years before him, but they understood it better.

Heidegger was very anti science and anti technology. He thought that scientific / mathematical investigation of nature that Husserl was so excited about is artificial, it is a result of 2000 year long distortion of the understanding being. Authentic understanding of being is by looking at phenomena and how they unfold themselves to us in experience. Any other approach (especially Plato's forms / ideas) covers up being, and leads to mistaken doctrines such as scholasticism, platonism, modern mathematics and analytic philosophy. In "Being and time" he starts with Dasein, which is the foundation of ontology as he saw it, then there is the question of being as equipment, and finally there is being as substance, on which mathematics and modern science are based. This last way of accessing being is derived, artificial, and not primordial, we only get it when our equipment breaks / does not work as expected. Also Heidegger wrote an big essay on technology and all the negative ways affects everything.

Foucault was a Nietzsciean, and for him knowledge is always linked to power. Science is yet another way that the non-elites get oppressed. It is always hierarchical and dominant. Especially psychiatry. Technology is as such is oppressive, he would probably think of modern day IT as an extension of the all seeing eye. As far as I know he did not talk about modern physics / maths.

It is hard to classify Lacan as a postmodernist, and he was neutral towards technology. In seminar 3 he says that the Symbolic order does function in ways that resemble some advanced calculating machines (those early computers). He did not care about physics, but he was interested in topology, game theory and set theory.

Deleuze was pro-science. He was very knowledgeable in biology. He was against oppression and vertical control, but he was for "horizontal" technology that does not oppress. Interestingly, his concept of rhizomatic organization anticipates the internet. This de-centralized network is a perfect example of technology that Deleuze was for. In his Anti-Oedipus" he described humans as 'desire-machines'.

Derrida was not interested in the subject of technology, and it is probably safe to say his view was close to Heidegger's.

Comment: Foucault isn't Nietzchean in any essential way. Whilst Nietzsche would regard minorities, the weak, the oppressed with contempt, Foucault did the opposite.

Comment: yes, you are correct, but for both of them knowledge=power. foucault was a nietzsciean just like deleuze was

Comment: "Also Heidegger wrote an big essay on technology and all the negative ways **it** affects everything."?

Comment: I read commentaries which explain that science is seen by Foucault as torture, and that scientific and technical reason is seen only in its instrumental dimension. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Nietzsche was questioning Christianity and not modernity. It was Foucault who rehabilitated his legacy after WWII when his reputation was mud. Personally, I think he should have left it there.

Post-modernity is not anti-reason but nor is it anti-modern. It questions modernity critically as it sees that as another grand narrative and it sees all grand narratives as suspect. It is a modern form of scepticism.

Post-modernity is not anti-technology but it critically evaluates our relationship with technology and especially the modern religion of eulogising technology as well as progress.

Comment: Yes, so it reflects my response to Mauro above.

Comment: Nietzsche was against democracy, against liberalism, against many forms of equality, including the modern movements of socialism and feminism (since he was misogynist). He was for aristocracy. So Nietzsche was against modernity.

Comment: @Starckman Sure, but was it the same "modernity" as targeted by Foucault, Derrida, Deleuze? There is a big time difference.

Comment: @Frank Maybe not, because Nietzsche wrote at the end of the 19th century, while the French postmodernists wrote during the 2nd part of the 20th century, so "modernity" certainly did not have the same meaning. But this is not my point. Here I am just responding to the stance "Nietzsche was questioning Christianity and not modernity"

Comment: Or were you referring to the sentence in my post "Postmodernism is anti-reason and anti-modernity."? To me modernity means what was brought by the Enlightenment: equality (which covers many things from equal rights, to feminism, to socialism), freedom, democracy, capitalism, rationalism, modern science, etc.

Comment: The latter. In your original post, you mention Nietzsche, then Foucault, ... but those are really two different epochs, with two world wars in between, and many ideas before "post-modernism". Nietzsche could be distantly seminal for "post-modernism", but he couldn't "mean" the same thing as those later French philosophers.

Comment: @Frank Indeed, Nietzsche's postmodernism is not the same as "French Theory" postmodernism, but I believe there is sufficiently a continuity and a familiarity between the two so that all can be embraced inside a larger "postmodernism" category, which would not have exactly the same meaning as "postmodernism" as referring to the writings of the "French Theory"

Comment: @Frank Do you think French postmodernism is still alive in France? I feel not really. I don't really understand why btw. They should have produced a lot of students, but were are these students? Lacanian psychanalysis (as psychanalysis in general) on the other hand, is still very present

Comment: @Starckman Interestingly, I know that Lacanian psychanalysis is alive in France and Argentina, maybe other countries in Europe, but not really in the Anglo-Saxon world. For postmodernism, not sure. Maybe the intellectual landscape became different after May '68.